# Is every state space model transformable to transfer function and vice versa?

Tags: control

I'm looking for a mathematical proof or example of non tranformable model, and I couldn't find any.

Comment: Are you assuming that the state space model is minimal (observable and controllable)?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, I assume that the state space model is observable and controllable.